# Why won't my <legend> element display inline?

Tags: html, css, styles, legend, fieldset

I am trying to apply `display: inline;` to the `<legend>` element in my `<fieldset>` element, so that the following `<span>` will follow on the same line, but my CSS is having no effect.

```css
legend{
    display: inline;
}
span {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <span>Follower</span>
</fieldset>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjnyV/)

**EDIT**

I have no control over the HTML; I can only edit CSS

Comment: `<legend>` elements are "dodgy". Have you considered simply moving the `<span>` inside the `<legend>`?

Comment: Can you not make 2 spans inside `legend` to do what you want? `<legend><span>Legend</span><span>Follower</span></legend>`

Comment: have edited question to make problem clearer.

Comment: I'm confused, just came back to accept an answer and it's gone!!

Comment: But if it is the only way to make it work as I require, then it is still the right answer. The answer is right, the implementation of the legend tag is wrong!

Comment: Related issue in Firefox's Bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653870

Comment: Related issue in Chrome's Bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481983

Comment: @MildFuzz If you remove the `<fieldset>` element, Firefox will now display `<legend>` inline.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Legends are special.  In particular, their default rendering can't be described in CSS, so browsers use non-CSS means of rendering them.  What that means is that a statically positioned legend will be treated like a legend and be separate from the actual content of the fieldset.

The weird doesn't end there; if you reverse the order of the span and the legend, the legend will *still* show up on top in most browsers (but not in Opera, apparently).

Comment: "default rendering can't be described in CSS" What does this mean, and why is it the case? Sounds like a bad way to implement HTML elements, to me.

Comment: It means what it says: the traditional fieldset rendering can't actually be expressed in CSS.  In particular the fact that the legend will make the fieldset wider as needed and the way the fieldset's border draws around the legend.

Answer (score 31):

Legends just don't accept `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`, but you can give it `float: left` and it will display similarly to what you want.

Comment: This works for me, with Firefox 51.0.1 and IE 11, but is this reliable?

Comment: @R.Schreurs I've had plenty of success with it... I also use `width: fit-content` for the legend if I am not supporting IE 11/Edge