# How do I use the <legend> element with styles?

Tags: html, css, legend

I just ran into a quirky problem and haven't been able to find an answer or figure it out.

The problem is regarding the `<legend>` tag within a `<form>`.

I've created a form using `<form>` and when I use `<fieldset>` with `<legend>` nested inside, the page renders normally, just fine!

When I use `<form>` without `<fieldset>` but continue to use `<legend>`, the page breaks.

Specifically, the `<legend>` text does not conform to the style I applied to `<body>` under `<style>`. Instead of centering the text, it's on the left. (see code..)

This is probably something really stupid on my part but yeah, I'm stumped. The only thing I can think of is that `<legend>` cannot be used on its own (without an element like `<fieldset>`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Misha's Homepage</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:black;
                text-align:center;
                color:white
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <hr>
        <p title="Carpe Diem">If you are reading this, well, we've only just begun.</p>
        <h2>Stay Hungry...</h2>
        <h3>Stay Foolish!</h3>
 <a href="https://youtu.be/2fAP-5NVZAA">Velocidas Eradico</a>
        <h1>Squad Up!</h1>
        <img src="ak_cartoon_whiteONclear2.jpg" alt="Get Sum." style="width:302px;height:217px">
        <form>
            <legend>Gimme Yo Digitz!</legend>
            <br>First Name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>Last Name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br>
            <br>Choose:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="state" value="bored">Bored
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="state" value="sleepy">Sleepy
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="state" value="horny">Horny
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Hit it!">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: A `legend` **requires** a `fieldset` AFAIK - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, to be valid, maybe. But not to show up: http://jsfiddle.net/mhxohq11/

Comment: For some more info from someone who works on web browsers, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5820013/2756409) from a related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`legend` **must** be placed within `fieldset`. It is like `table` and its related elements, you can't have `td` or `th` without `tr`.

There is a funny fact about the `legend` element a lot of people don't know is that if you place `legend` anywhere within a `fieldset` it will always show on top of the `fieldset`. Like `tfoot` inside `table`, it will always render after `tbody` even if you placed it on top in the HTML.

Example:

```html
<fieldset>
    <span>Content</span>
    <legend>Title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Even though the `<legend>` element above is written *after* the `<span>` element, it still renders at the top of the `<fieldset>` element.

Comment: I added a code example to help illustrate what your post is saying. Feel free to remove it/rework it if you wish.

Comment: @TylerH this is exactly what I wanted to add, thanks for your contribution!